# I cannot output the correct "Time" the simulation took to finish

Tags: java, rinsim

I am using the ExperimentExample base, I implemented a custom stop condition for when AGVs finish delivering Parcels and there are no more Parcels available. Additionally I implemented a custom PostProcessor; here I am trying to obtain the time it took for the simulation to complete. I use the following code:

```
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (!sim.isPlaying()){
        sb.append(", simulation has completed.")
        .append("\n")
        .append("Duration:").append(sim.getCurrentTime());
    }return sb.toString();
```

However the output is always the same, regardless if I introduce more Parcels, which logically takes more time. I am constantly getting a result of Duration:174000

How can I get the real time?
UPDATE:SOLVED!
The time is correct. My problem was the number of AGVs was larger than the number of parcels, therefore the time they took to deliver more parcels was very similar as an idle AGV became active from a simulation to the other.